# Is adding a tag to a question without the author's input acceptable when you can't be sure of the author's intent?

Tags: discussion

Apologies for the lengthy title. I could not think of a more succinct way to phrase this.

The events prompting this question: I posted an answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86620/holding-two-weapons-but-not-using-two-weapon-fighting) in which I guessed the system that the author was asking about since it was not specified in the question or in the tags. My answer was removed since (understandably) guessing at the system the author intended is not good practice.

The question was closed as being "unclear what you are asking" but then edited by a separate user to add a tag specifying the version of the game (5e in this instance, although I'm not sure that matters). That edit was approved by the community and the question was reopened.

My question is this: **When the system is important to the question but not specified in the question, is it acceptable to guess at the author's intent when editing/tagging that post?**

Comment: The answers to this question have been merged into another to produce a consolidated FAQ. Thanks for having asked this last year.