# How to show the most recent community consensus in meta?

Tags: discussion, policy, meta

This meta: [What to do when an edit guesses the system being used rather than waiting for the querent to clarify?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th)

is an old post that has received [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

However, there is an attempt to revisit the policy: [Revisiting our "never guess the game system" policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/revisiting-our-never-guess-the-game-system-policy) which is newer. The answer is still unchanged "no", though.

Given that it is a more recent discussion, should we VTC the **old** question as duplicate and point it to the newer one (and move the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) status), or point the **new** one to old question?

Answer (score 10):

They’re not really duplicates.

Just looking at the two question posts, the “revisit” is a terrible candidate for the Q part of “FAQ”: it’s long and detailed and not asking the direct question the FAQ should be about. It’s really more a meta-meta discussion opener than a FAQ.

Since there’s no change in stance, and there’s no improvement offered by the later discussion, the original FAQ is still the best reference.

If there had been a change, rather than making a debate meta into a new FAQ, better would be to write a new FAQ as a new question post and answer it succinctly. If our stance changes in the future, that would make a much more readable FAQ replacement.

In the meantime, it’s worth having the FAQ linked to the later discussion. A comment should be enough.

Comment: I've [added such a comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th#comment27622_6867) to the 2017 question. I also totally agree with the assessment that we would have made a new FAQ had the consensus changed; the revisit was only ever meant to be a discussion and not a go-to reference point on the topic.