# What is the process for establishing and maintaining policies?

Tags: discussion, policy, meta

The core question I'm looking to get an answer for is "What is a policy and how does it function?". Specifically, how does something become policy, and who is responsible for maintaining or reviewing those policies?

As a way to prompt answers to this core question, some sub-questions that might be addressed in answers are:

- Is there any kind of official guidelines that govern policies?
- What determines if a policy is valid or not?
- How do votes interact with policies?
- How are contentious policies handled?
- Is a majority needed to implement a policy, is consensus needed, or something else?
- Are moderators be allowed to overrule policies?
- What happens if a user does not follow a policy?
- Do policies get less valid with age?
- How long do policies last for?
- How are contradictory or conflicting policies handled?
- Can a more specific policy overrule part of a less specific policy?
- When are policies revisited?
- Does revisiting a policy invalidate the original?
- How should users determine what a policy is?
- Do policies need to be followed all the time, or just some times?

Comment: Heavily related: [What are the rules and policies of RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11176/48759)

Comment: @linksassin thanks, that one sentence "A policy is enacted by community consensus on meta, following discussions." could use a lot of fleshing out! Plus, in my limited experience, it's not accurate in the first place. Should I edit that link in to the question? If that is the starting point there's a lot of work to be done.

Comment: You are welcome to edit the link into the question. But you are highly unlikely to get a clearer answer than that. That is the best statement of what policies are and how they are established we have. There simply isn't a general case that can be codified for all so-called 'policies'.

Comment: @linksassin I see, well I guess now is the time to figure out these questions!

Comment: While this is arguably way too broad a topic for a single post, given that it contains 15 different questions within it... The fact is that many of these things are simply not strictly defined (as indicated by @linksassin's comment above), so actually splitting this post into 15 different Q&As on meta may not be helpful either.

Comment: Another relevant Q&A: [How to show the most recent community consensus in meta?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8607/33569)

Comment: @V2Blast Rubiksmoose the core question is just "what is a policy and how does it function", the list of questions can be taken as prompts. A good answer about what a policy is would probably answer all of them without having to go into specifics.

Comment: @user-024673 based on that comment, I've made an edit, to try and focus the question to that core query, while retaing the "prompt" questions. If I've done so erroneously please revert back the question!

Comment: @illustro No, I think it's fine, thanks!

Comment: Wait, what happened to their account?  Did they make a 2nd account and merge it with the old one?

Comment: We can't comment on moderation activity or private information and we ask people to refrain from speculation here in the comments. We can only say that the profile that was used to create this post was merged with the profile you see now which is what caused the apparent change in name.

Comment: I have a book recommendation that I hope you'll take advantage of: [How to Win Friends and Influence People](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=56185571#56185571) by Dale Carnegie

Answer (score 14):

#### Answering the individual questions

Note that these "answers" are informal and reflect what I have seen occur *in the past* with these types of situations; they do not reflect what has always happened or will always happen, only what I would call the "typical" results:

**Is there any kind of official guidelines that govern policies?**

Aside from the following Q&A I am not aware of any rigid (or loose) guidelines regarding policies; only what generally happens to happen:

- [What are the rules and policies of RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11176)

**What determines if a policy is valid or not?**

I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you use the word "valid"; just about anything can be a policy if it has (Meta) community consensus.

**How do votes interact with policies?**

Often, policies stem from questions *about* policies. That is, a question will ask how/whether something should be done and answers will give differing, well, answers to that question. The highest-scoring answer is likely to be considered the "policy" answer, as it is the one with the most (Meta) community consensus.

**How are contentious policies handled?**

Policies can be revisited after they are made (I at least believe that they *should* be as otherwise it would be tradition for tradition's sake and current policies wouldn't reflect the current state of the site). That said, how *often* policies can be revisited is not something I have seen answered anywhere.

Note that contending with a policy does not change the fact that *it is the policy* and that it must be followed.

**Is a majority needed to implement a policy, is consensus needed, or something else?**

The highest-scoring answer to a question about a policy is the one that is the most agreed upon by the (Meta) community (or at least something similar to being the most agreed upon answer). Thus this is the answer that is, for lack of a better word, "promoted" into being a policy.

**Are moderators be allowed to overrule policies?**

Well, I'm not a moderator, but moderators *are* site users just like everybody else and they (as far as I'm aware) cannot assume any sort of dictatorial or "because I said so" sort of stance. They must follow policies just like regular site members.

**What happens if a user does not follow a policy?**

Ideally, they would have the current policy explained to them and would learn from it moving forward by following the policy in the future. Whatever policy-defying action they took would almost certainly be undone but I certainly don't believe people should expect users (especially new users) to know the various policies of RPG.SE which are buried across numerous posts on an almost completely separate site.

**Do policies get less valid with age?**

I don't believe they get "less valid" but they certainly get less *reliable* in the sense that *they reflect less the *current* state of the site*. If a policy stood for 50 years one would certainly hope that the reasons the policy was ever implemented were still around and if they weren't still around, one would certainly hope that the policy be revisited as the times had changed.

**How long do policies last for?**

There is not set time that I am aware of. Policies are changed by being revisited, so without a revisit I suppose they would last indefinitely (unless of course the policy *came* with an expiration date, which I have never seen happen).

**How are contradictory or conflicting policies handled?**

These should not ever exist. If two policies contradict one another *this is a fundamental problem* that should be pointed out and addressed quickly enough that the contradiction has little to no effect on the sites.

**Can a more specific policy overrule part of a less specific policy?**

Without a specific example this is probably unanswerable. However, as far as I'm aware, policies can do whatever they want (while avoiding contradictions); after all, it's just an agreed upon set of rules.

**When are policies revisited?**

I don't know. There is probably an *entire* separate Meta discussion buried in here that I don't want to hash out.

**Does revisiting a policy invalidate the original?**

The answers and votes and comments and time that users spent on the original question are still noteworthy, valuable, and available; so it isn't invalidated in that sense. However, yes, the *entire* point of revisiting a policy is to either change or maintain the then-current policy (you could call this "invalidating" it).

**How should users determine what a policy is?**

*Generally* if a question is asking about how something should be done or whether something should be done; the highest-scoring answer is going to be the current policy. That doesn't mean *every* Meta Q&A is about policies (we probably have very very few actually policies at all), and it is only the case *generally*. Recently, the moderators have gone and added little sections of text to the end of some policy questions describing what the current policy actually is in case it would/could otherwise be unclear.

**Do policies need to be followed all the time, or just some times?**

The *entire* point of a policy is that it is *always* followed by everybody. However, context, context, context: It matters and shapes our ideas around things because we *know* a policy can't be perfect and account for every possible future event, I mean, we can't even accurately imagine every possible future event so we have no chance of accounting for them all anyway. We just do our best here and we know situations and events can occur where a "policy" gets... complicated.

---

#### I at least do not *want* a rigidly-defined process

To me, having a rigidly defined method of creating and establishing policies (such as through implementing a set time after which the highest-scoring answer is promoted into a policy) gives easy ways to track down errors, loopholes, and ways to abuse or cheat the system.

A quote that summaries much of how I feel about the "policies" here:

> [...] I wish the word "policy" weren't getting slung around so much. Like it or not, we don't really have *policies* nearly as much as we have *practices*. There are very few things around here that anyone--editor, voter, moderator, employee--is going to say is so clear that "yes, this will be applied in *all* situations, no consideration given, no context needed."

We aren't a legal system, we aren't a rigidly defined system of checks and balances. We're people trying their best, and we *know* that a rule can *always* have an exception. You simply *cannot* see the future.

Comment: Oh thanks! This is a lot of great info! I'll make some comments are a read along :) I say "valid" meaning "in use", for example an old superseded policy isn't "valid". You say "consensus" but do you just mean "has the most votes"? Maybe it's a dialect thing, but I take consensus to mean basically unanimous, not "51%" kind of thing. Maybe the 5e policy isn't a great example, as it seems to be kind of a hostile policy in the first place (eg saying that D&D expects "guess" systems, implying D&D players are stupid, etc), so I guess it's a special case and that's why the contradiction happened?

Comment: It's good that moderators have started doing that, it would definitely help clear up the problem of policy threads being useless to new users. You say the entire point of policies are that they are always followed by everyone, a couple of users have told me they do not think that is the case which I find very interesting. I don't believe these are troublemakers or clueless users too. Again, thanks for all the great info, this is super valuable for new users!!

Comment: @user-024673 What I've seen is that the highest-scoring answer (after some unpredictable but often at least one month) amount of time is considered to be the most suitable as a policy. Of course, other metrics could be used and other methods but that gets into a debate that's been held countless times throughout the history of the world. There's no percent requirement, just having the highest score (score = #upvotes - #downvotes).

Comment: Again, the "never guess the system policy" is rather poorly named as it used the term "guess" when it really means "editing in a system tag when the OP has not perfectly, entirely, and explicitly stated the system (and edition, if applicable) that they are playing.  Furthermore, the "Is 5e a clear statement of system" question is truly an exceptional event in that the highest-scoring answer changed after a policy had been established. The moderators leaving little policy declarations on the questions will likely prevent any similar confusion in the future.

Comment: Regarding your statement about policies *not* needing to be followed; I would assume that either you misinterpreted something somebody said, what was being talked about was not *actually* a policy but only a guideline, or (and I *do* believe this to be highly unlikely) somebody actually violated a policy here. If they actually did, I would imagine (and hope) that their action was undone

Comment: @user-024673 Are you able to link to the cases of users saying policies don't need to be followed by everyone (assuming I understood you correctly). I would very much like the full context for those statements, because it sounds like there may be an misunderstanding somewhere (which would best be clarified, else the sprouting discussions may be more harmful than fruitful).

Comment: @Medix2 Agreed that the policy is a bit degrading, definitely not ideal to word it in such a hostile and confusing way. Regarding people saying policies don't have to be followed here are a few links for you and Someone_Evil: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54436995#54436995 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56130217#56130217

Comment: @user-024673 None of those actually say people don't have to follow policy. They talk about wishing that 'policy' wasn't the term. There is a difference there.

Comment: @NautArch I believe you did not finish reading the quotes I linked. The first very clearly and explicitly says that policies do not have to be followed all the time. The second says that pragmatically policies are more like conversations than laws. Please check again.

Comment: You need to stop reading what you want in statements others make. You could interpret that as what was said, but it is not actually explicitly and clearly saying that. Your approach is tainted by your assumptions.

Comment: @NautArch I am not sure how to interpret "There are very few things around here that anyone--editor, voter, moderator, employee--is going to say is so clear that "yes, this will be applied in all situations, no consideration given, no context needed."" in any way other than "policies do not have to be followed 100% of the time", it actually seems to me to imply that most people believe policies are not absolute. Apologies if my interpretation is not correct :/

Comment: Just stop interpreting. If you want clarification, please ask. But you need to stop trying to guess what other people mean.

Comment: @user-024673 More guidelines than rules; and if you haven't seen the movie *Pirates of the Caribbean* (the first one) I'd recommend it for two reasons: first of all, it's a fun, swashbuckling movie and secondly they make frequent references to *guidelines rather than rules* which I think is useful for this conversation. FWIW, those two chat entries you cited are well expressed points by experienced users that don't seem to mean what you think that they mean.  (No, my name is not Inigo Montoya, so you are safe   )

Comment: @NautArch Would you mind explaining then?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I would usually think of guidelines as things that are flexible, so to say "they must be followed 100% of the time no matter what - but they are guidelines rather than rules" doesn't make much sense to me! I think you fall in the other camp, where you think of them as flexible, but that isn't generally agreed upon.

Comment: I can't explain what someone else means, either. It is not my place to do so. I'm simply saying you need to stop making these interpretations.

Comment: @user-024673 for informal groups, norms are at least as important as policies.  I don't see this stack as a formal group, so I am more interested in norms than in policy, which carries with it a heavy-handed connotation

Answer (score -9):

## There is no agreement on many of these topics

The thing that has struck me is that there is very little agreement on fundamental things like "what is a policy", "what determines if a policy is valid", or "how does revisiting a policy work". I have received many different opinions, very close to 1 per person.

I suspect that even of "meta" had 100% agreement (which it is nowhere near close to) that still leaves the vast majority of users that policies affect in anarchy. I think this is a substantial issue since policies affect these users.

I'm just writing here the answers I gather from other people as I go; I know there isn't much established knowledge on this topic, so everything is a bit random. I have heard many conflicting opinions on how things run, I'm noting them down here as that indicates further discussion is needed. Medix's post is great but it's still just 1 person's opinion - I have added their points to this post too.

### **Is there any kind of official guidelines that govern policies?**

No, and the idea of "policy" isn't exactly agreed upon either - some users have suggested alternate times for the concept to reduce confusion, eg "practice".

### **What determines if a policy is valid or not?**

Policies are valid so long as another policy hasn't invalidated them and they previously achieved "consensus" - I have heard several opinions as to what "consensus" means, I'll discuss them in the next point.

Old policies are still valid, they just may have lost a bit of their context. Whether or not these hap-hazardous policies need to be followed is a point of debate in the community.

### **How do votes interact with policies?**

A question is posted, and people post their suggested policies as answers; after a voting period, the highest-voted answer is "the policy". There is no set "voting period", so it's on a case-by-case basis. After that, voting may change, so the highest-voted answer may not be the actual policy, as it may have been voted up after that voting period ended.

Generally it is held that the top answer is valid if it has some amount of margin, but that margin is hotly debated. Here are some opinions I have heard:

1. Simple majority is enough, even if it's only by 1 vote.
2. A substantial majority, 1 vote isn't enough, but a good lead of 5 or 10 votes is plenty (note that most policies only get around 20 votes at most, so this is a 25-50% lead).
3. Unanimity, most of the meta community need to be in agreement, alternate answers should have far fewer votes (although no guidelines as to what this means exactly, it should be >50%).

Keep in mind that often people suggest very similar policies, so the top 3 answers may have similar levels of votes, even the same number of votes. However if these are all basically the same policy, then that is good enough. In this case first answer is usually picked as the policy.

However, this is not universally agreed on. Some users say that the top post is "the policy" regardless of the "voting period" - the history doesn't matter, only the current top answer does.

### **How are contentious policies handled?**

Newer policies overrule older policies, even if the older policy was more specific. If people disagree with the policy, they can post a thread to revisit it.

### **Are moderators be allowed to overrule policies?**

No. Sometimes it may appear that a moderator is overruling a policy because they are stating the opposite of the top post(s); but they are actually just restating the policy as it was at the end of the voting period. Mods aren't supposed to overrule policies.

### **What happens if a user does not follow a policy?**

It seems like this issue is not well known, there are a lot of different opinions as to what happens.

1. Nothing directly, but other users may downvote/vote to delete a user's posts if they are not following the policy. This can lead to the system automatically banning the user for a short time (called a suspension).
2. An alternate theory is that the system won't ban you; it will just stop you from asking questions, and this only happens if your questions are getting downvoted - there's no penalty for not following policies with regard to answers.
3. Some users have said that this is not correct, moderators can and do ban users directly for not following policies.

Additionally, Moderators can also enforce their stance on policies by deleting comments/answers and applying greater penalties as they see fit - there aren't guides on this; it is up to the moderator's judgement.

### **Do policies get less valid with age?**

No, but they can be overruled, and since the votes on the answers can change that means the policy can look like it's saying the opposite of what it really says. They also become less reliable in that the site may have changed significantly since the policy's inception. If you follow the school of thought of "policies should be applied only if it makes sense in context", then older policies probably apply less often.

This thinking doesn't exist in the "everyone must always follow policies" model.

### **How are contradictory or conflicting policies handled?**

The newer policy is the right one. When conflicting policies exist this can lead to one or both policies being revisited.

One point to be clear about is that if a policy is revisited and the thread is either inconclusive or to retain the policy, that invalidates all policies that may otherwise have overruled it.

For example in 2015 policy A is made. Then in 2016 policy B is made which overrules A. In 2017 there is a thread to revisit policy A. If this re-visitation is inconclusive or to reaffirm policy A, then that would overrule policy B.

Some users interpret inconclusive votes to mean that the policy is abolished.

### **Can a more specific policy overrule part of a less specific policy?**

Newer policies overrule older ones. Specific or general doesn't matter.

### **When are policies revisited?**

Any user can start a re-visitation of a policy.

### **Does revisiting a policy invalidate the original?**

There are two schools of thought:

1. Revisiting the policy invalidates the later regardless of the outcome
2. Revisiting the policy only invalidates the later if the outcome is to overthrow it

Revisiting policies can lead to either reaffiriming the previous policy, introducing a new policy, abolishing the policy, or a moderators could deem it "too contentious" - this is at moderator discretion; as far as I know, there are no guidelines like "it needs 20% more votes to pass", etc.

### **How should users determine what a policy is?**

There is no way for users to do this besides asking around and seeing what people say. However, recently some policies have been moved to Q&A posts, which overrule all policy discussion threads and correctly list the policy. Checking Q&A seems to be, at this time, the only reliable way to determine what a policy is.

### **Do policies need to be followed all the time, or just some times?**

There seem to be 2 schools of thought on this:

1. Policies should be followed in all situations, no consideration given, no context needed.
2. Always follow policies all the time - but keep in mind the context is important; policies are not perfect and cannot predict every situation.
3. Policies are more like practices. How the policy fits the situation is more important than dogmatically following the policy.

From a pragmatic point of view, the downside of not following a policy is the downvotes and potential deletion. It is not unheard of for even a popular and high rep user to be banned due to this (although it is unclear if it was automatic or by mods).

This site only considers fraudulent votes to be serial upvoting/downvoting, so voting based on policy is ok here.

Comment: This answer makes assumptions and oversimplifications that are largely incorrect, hence the downvotes. However there are a few remarks regarding the role of moderators I would like to clarify to prevent misinformation.
General guidelines for moderators can be found in the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). Moderators are just regular users whose posts and opinions can be voted on just like anyone else. We do not override policies at whim, or dictate when they should be revisited. We simply enforce policy to the best of our ability based on meta discussions.

Comment: @linksassin Would you mind explaining where the assumptions and oversimplifications are? I am repeating information given to me by experienced users and moderators here, so it seems like there is quite a problem if what one would expect to be trusted users are not seeing eye to eye. With regards to moderators, I definitely did not say you are doing things on a whim, I'm not sure how you got that impression but I don't want to be mischaracterised. What I have seen is that you personally posted overriding a policy, again, not on a whim, but it did happen. Recent "revisits" were made by mods too.

Comment: @linksassin Keep in mind that I am trying to resolve conflicting information here, so to have one user say "this is right" and then other say "this is wrong" is not all that productive! Especially coupled with confusing statements like "mods are regular users" when taking an authoritarian stance - either explain or dictate, but don't refuse to explain and say you aren't dictating! You know what I mean, right?

Comment: In short, any place that your post differs from Medix2's is likely incorrect. Particularly any remark you make about moderators or bans. I have done nothing but try to help explain the situation to you and find a solution to issues you highlighted. I find you characterizing my (or other mods) actions as "dictating" offensive, please desist from this line of comments. I personally have reached out to try to explain things to you but you declined.

Comment: I did not override a policy, but clarified what the established policy was and that the vote had made the meta misleading. The recent 'revisit' was posted by a mod yes, but others have been posted by non-mods. Nothing prevents other users from posted a revisit, they are simply more likely to be posted by a mod as we try to keep an eye on what policies might be causing problems on the site and suggest revisits to improve those policies for all users.

Comment: @linksassin that was days (weeks?) ago about another matter. It feels disingenuous for you to be dismissive of me then claim that since one time in the past you asked if I was free for a chat that should even things out. I assume you are misreading my comments and not doing this on purpose, but I do find it annoying. Thank you for providing clarification that non-mods can revisit policies too. I will change the part where you overrode the policy and say that you stated it, the system is confusing so I hope you can understand why I'm confused.

Comment: So this answer is mostly technically correct. There's a mischaracterization about how mods work, because this is from the perspective of a new user. To explain: Moderators are still site users, so they are expected to follow policies regardless of personal stance. A rogue moderator *could* enforce their own opinions over the site consensus, but doing so would be a misuse of mod powers and would have consequences.

Comment: The claim *"if you are a high rep popular user, you don't have to follow them"* is wrong. High-reputation users are still subject to the same rules as everyone else, and their bad answers can still be downvoted and deleted.  Regardless of reputation, a user's repeated violations or harassment can still get them suspended or banned.  Reputation measures a user's participation over time, but is otherwise meaningless, and doesn't give a user permission to ignore the rules.

Comment: @MikeQ Hm, but from a pragmatic point of view, people aren't going to downvote their friends, and a high rep user probably won't care about potential downvotes will they? I will list the downsides without commentary to keep it more accurate though. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: People can upvote or downvote whoever they want. I like many folks here and I downvote their bad answers regularly. Other than the 20 rep needed to participate in the mainsite chat, *rep is meaningless.*

Comment: @MikeQ Sure, but SE is built around rep heavily, and there are no rules for voting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116256/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-user-024673).

Comment: This high rep popular user - me - got suspended for 30 days a couple of years ago. Just to let you know that you've missed the mark at least once in your answer. As to this - *but from a pragmatic point of view, people aren't going to downvote their friends* is demonstrably false.  One of my long time friends here, (NautArch), down votes me with some frequency when he feels I've put out low quality stuff.  (As well he should, eh?)  He usually leaves a comment (it helps that we trust each other). Sometimes I respond, and maybe the DV goes away if he finds the correction sound; sometimes not.

Comment: As to this "there are no rules for voting" I suggest that you go and read up on voting at the help center.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You do not feel that as an experienced user you face less scrutiny than a brand new user? That is counter to my experience in this community, it seems that experienced users are given a lot of leeway. As you can see a I long since removed that line, but I will add in your comment, thanks for the input! Do you happen to know if you got scooped up by a script or a mod banned you?

Comment: @user-024673 SE is a particular kind of community.  Their attitude (collectively)  is "adapt or FO". I am not the needy sort who needs affirmation on line. So I participate, or not, based on what I feel like doing.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm not sure what your comment is alluding to, but good for you! Glad you are enjoying the site!

Comment: You should at least consider that there is a direct correlation between reputation and quality of content. New users are statistically more likely to provide lower quality content due to lack of experience and familiarity with expectations. Poor content being filtered out is the system working as intended, and that low rep users provide more low quality content than high rep user shouldn’t be surprising.

Comment: @user-024673 The general aim of SE and SO sites is "High signal to noise ratio" - which a great many users fail to grasp as they participate. True for users, new, medium, and old.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Those are two different concepts you are talking about. Statistically low rep users produce low quality content more often than high rep users, sure. But that doesn't mean you should automatically treat every new user with hostility or more harshly. It seems to me that the higher the rep the higher the standard, not the opposite.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Agreed, but do you think it's better to focus on content or users?

Comment: @user-024673 Why do you think that it's an either - or proposition?  Those who can't  handle the fact that not every opinion has value, and that not every ejaculation deserves a name, seem to be the kind of folks who don't find SE to be a place that they care for.  Informed and well researched positions, however, are usually welcomed.  And that's the crux of the biscuit - **show your work** - be ye Asker or Answerer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Well, we are talking about whether new users should be held to a higher standard, so it seems to me that looking at the post content is better than their rep. If a new user and old user make the same post, shouldn't the reaction be the same? As I said before, if anything we should be holding the experienced user to a higher standard as I think they should know better. We shouldn't be more harsh with a newbie then say "oh well they are probably low quality anyway".

Comment: @user-024673 The modern complaint of "I have value because I draw breath" isn't a position that fits into SE's "High signal to noise ration" model: Forums, Facebook, and Twitter is a fine place for all of that.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I agree, but that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: @user-024673 No. It is not whether new users are to be held to a "higher standard."  It's "have you bothered to put in the work"  that's the core issue to hand... and if you will bother to put in the work, you will find that I am an advocate for New Users on this Meta.  So, use your ability to search and read up on that.  I have caught no small amount of feces for taking that position.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Well, it seems to me that if "have you bothered to put in the work" then that is certainly biasing towards experienced users who have perhaps proven to you they have value, and thus can do things that new users can't. I have to say, your comment feels a bit hostile. Here you are advocating for experienced users against new users and then you seem to insult me for not knowing that at one time in the past you believed the opposite. I don't get it.

Comment: @user-024673 Well, I had to learn how SE worked the hard way.  I put in the work.  My initial experience was very frustrating but I figured it out.  Do thee likewise.  And then, once I figured it out, I spoke up about what an FU'd experience it is for new users and was told "deal with it" ... and a few years later, the Powers that Be of SE/SO finally got a freaking clue.  But not because of anything I said or did.  They were deaf to my pleas. It took being shamed on Twitter for SE to wake the hell up.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Wouldn't it be nicer if you didn't have to learn the hard way and it wasn't frustrating and it wasn't a FU'd experience and you weren't told to "adapt or FO" or to "deal with it"? Sounds nice to me.

Comment: @user-024673 Yes, it was frustrating, but I have a spine.  Again, the new user experience is better now; if this now frustrates you, then I suggest growing one.  Yeah.  It's better now.  And it can still be very frustrating.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am glad you made it out ok, but I am not sure that is a good justification for hostility towards new users. Even though you have a spine, surely this was not a good experience for you. I do not believe that abuse builds character.

Comment: @user-024673 If you take my remarks as "justification" they I can't  help you.  I am trying to tell you what is, not some fantasy world of "I wish it were like this"

Comment: @KorvinStarmast So you are saying that hostility towards new users is just the way it is?

Comment: @user-024673 No, that is a False Characterization of what I said. Please do not insult me, nor insult my intelligence, by using that "so" construction.  If you want an ally, you are doing a crap job of recruiting one.

Comment: For a somewhat different perspective, I spent three months doing nothing but reading the stack and learning how things worked and how to write good content. I wrote my first answer on June 4th of this year and have been the top user every month since. I am the #1 user in rep per day on the stack, and it’s because I took some time to learn what good content was and how the stack worked. I listened and learned before I began to post. I have had no trouble with the mods or anyone else because I assumed from the beginning that this is a meritocracy and the quality of my content is what matters.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am trying to clarify what you are saying, I do not mean to insult you. It seems to me that is what you are saying. Sorry that I have offended you.

Comment: @user-024673 Sorry, you have offended me, and "I am trying to clarify what you are saying" is "I am reframing what  you said in my words" - doing that offends me.  Don't pull that nonsense with me.  Now, please, stop treating this comment stream as a chat and go and do your due diligience: search my user name and the term new user. You obviously have not done that.  So, Do Your Homework.

Comment: @user-024673 Here's a clue on how to do this stuff.  There were 800 pages on this stack when I showed up in 2015. I read all of them before I made my first post.  Savvy?  Once again, I share your frustration with the new user experience: still, five years later.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You seem to think I'm some evil genius, I just misunderstood you that's all. You said "I am trying to tell you what is" and I interpreted that as "that is the way it is". I am not sure if that's dialect, but to me that it sounds like to me. Likewise, you characterized my view as "a fantasy world", do you think that is fair? It seems like this was purposeful, out of frustration I'm sure. But clearly we are not communicating as clearly as we should. It doesn't feel fair to scold me for chatting when you are the one I'm talking to :(

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You and KorvinStarmast both spent a long time reading before posting. I suspect you are not the only experienced users to do so. Spending months reading hundreds of threads is a significant investment of time and effort. My question to you is if you think this should be the cost of entry to the site, and if you think it's a reasonable or realistic ask for new users. Would like to hear your perspective if you think these hurdles are a good thing or bad, if you are lamenting those months or praising them.

Comment: @user-024673 Neither.  We each (heck, we all) approach a given environment from our own point of view.  As with other things in life, what you get out of it depends on what you put into it.  And I note that, once again, you have not done as I asked. That sends a message.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't want to mischaracterize you, but I find your comments hard to understand. It seems like you are saying that it's neither positive nor negative, it's just your experience, is that correct? You aren't so much saying that other users should do the same.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast With regard to reading through your old posts, sorry but it takes time. I have read through about a dozen out of 100+. I am not sure I understand the value but if it will prove that I am invested enough then I guess I have to

Comment: @user-024673 *It seems like you are saying that it's neither positive nor negative, it's just your experience, is that correct?* Bingo. You nailed it.  :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Cool, glad I got it right. I appreciate your patience, sometimes it is difficult to understand so I find clarifying by restating to be useful. With regard to new users, what do you think should be the minimum requirement to participate in the site should be?

Comment: The only requirement is a willingness to learn.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Well, ok. I am not sure how to interpret your previous post about spending months learning policies before even posting a single time meshes with what you just commented. Are you saying to become the top you need to frontload this huge amount of study, but for normal users who aren't that interested in rep it doesn't matter much? Sorry if my question is obtuse, I'm just not seeing how how experience with extreme study and saying that willingness is enough form a cohesive idea. To me the inaccessibility of the site is a bad thing, not a good thing.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to go back to the basic Stack Overload model, and the core Stack Exchange model.  The original design intent was expert answers to well researched questions.  (Mouse over the down vote button for more on that).  RPGSE is a sub set / spin off of the larger body of Stack Exchange sites.  It isn't Reddit.  It isn't a discussion forum.  It isn't Twitter.  It isn't quora.  @Thomas Markov's point on "willingness to learn" is absolutely spot on.  I have written technical manuals and monographs, but I still had to learn a new writing style for this format.  So, I did.

Comment: Agreed, I think that is a great idea!