# Is it acceptable to append the "dnd-5e" tag to questions that lack it but are about Adventurers League?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, policy, dnd-5e

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/150359/revisions) was missing the dnd-5e tag but is asking a question in the context of an Adventurers League game.

I know we have a policy against guessing game editions but, in this case, no guess was necessary. DDAL [runs 5th edition rules exclusively](https://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play).

I added the tag but the edit was rolled back by a moderator. May I get clarification on why adding the tag was deemed unacceptable?

Comment: It might be worth noting that the AL tag was edited in (not by OP) based on the reference to an "AL game". It may be perfectly obvious to us that D&D 5e AL is meant, but that might be considered guessing the system.

Comment: Would that mean that adding the Adventure League tag to a question that mentions "AL" would also be considered system guessing, then?

Comment: Maybe? In this case it seems to have amounted to effectively that, though one could argue between "adding the AL tag is guessing the system" and "adding the 5e tag because of AL tag is guessing". For the moment we seem to be using the latter, but it might be something for the community to decide, either as part of this Q, or a separate one.

Comment: Note that the addition of the DNDAL tag was also rolled back to avoid confusion and to bring the post back to the original state while this discussion was had.

Comment: Related metas: [What to do when an edit guesses the system being used rather than waiting for the querent to clarify?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th), [Revisiting our “never guess the game system” policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/revisiting-our-never-guess-the-game-system-policy), [What qualifies as guessing on a system?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/what-qualifies-as-guessing-on-a-system)

Comment: If you read the actual reason behind the policy on any of those metas, you will see why it's wrong even if "you're sure."

Comment: I take issue with this being a called a matter of "guessing" but acknowledge that the policy, in practice, is not "never guess" (however one defines that) but that it is "only the questioner may clarify/refine." That is a much clearer and accurate policy statement in my eyes.

Comment: @Rykara I think the point is that if you are not the OP then you have no way to be 100% certain. Therefore any assumption you make is by definition a guess, which we don't allow.

Comment: Surely if someone states that they're playing Adventurer's League, an organized play system which only exists for D&D 5th edition, then they're certainly playing D&D 5th edition.

Comment: Or we could remove [dnd-5e] tags from the effective system tag that is [dnd-adventurers-league]